# Internal variable handling in self executing function

Tags: javascript, this, private, public

I need in my namespace a function with "private" and "public" members and like to know, what happens internal, because I can't retrace the variable handling.

The public variable "publicVar" should be assigned directly like: "myNamespace.publicVar = true".

```
var myNamespace = (function() {
    var _privateVar = "not accessible",
        publicVar = false;

    function publicFoo() {
        if (publicVar) {
            console.log("var is true");
        } else {
            console.log("var is false");
        }
    }

    return {
        publicVar: publicVar,
        publicFoo: publicFoo
    }

})();

myNamespace.publicFoo();     // output--> var is false
myNamespace.publicVar = true;
myNamespace.publicFoo();     // output --> var is false
myNamespace.publicVar;       // output--> true of course.
```

What happens here? Why can't I change the "public" variable in this way, so that it is used internal correctly?
If I change the publicFoo() like this and use publicVar with "this", it works correctly:

```
    function publicFoo() {
        if (this.publicVar) {
            console.log("var is true");
        } else {
            console.log("var is false");
        }
    }
```

But can I avoid "this"? Or is there a better way to handle it?

```
myNamespace.publicFoo();       // output --> var is false
myNamespace.publicVar = true;
myNamespace.publicFoo();       // output --> var is true
```

Thanks a lot for answering.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you when you say,

`myNamespace.publicVar = true;`

It creates a `publicVar` on `myNamespace` object . **It does not updates variable internal to function.**

`publicVar` inside function is local and its only visible to internal function (closure in picture)